# What would cause SQL Server to stop writing to the error log?

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003

Error logs for our SQL Server instance are gathering a large amount of data (250k records in a month) all day, then all of a sudden stop at roughly the same time of day (9:15pm), though on different days of the week and at seemingly random intervals of days.

This corresponds to other issues on the server: 1) jobs that move files to shares on the database server fail 2) I am not able to access the server via any method (tried RDP and SSMS). Once the servers are rebooted, SQL Server comes up and SQL Server error logging resumes.

Windows Event Viewer doesn't show any notable error messages for System (the other event logs have wrapped already).

The error logs are being written to the D:\ drive, which has over 100GB free currently. The error log files are in the range of tens of megabytes.

Appreciate any ideas on what might have caused this or how troubleshoot it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cause *appears* to have been a corrupted maintenance plan. I discovered this by correlating the timing of the lock-up to the times the maintenance plan was running. The lack of logging made this difficult to confirm. Guessing that at least some parts of it ran normally, but got rolled back on restart.
The current fix was to disable the maintenance plan and replace it with a collection of jobs that do the same tasks. I will likely recreate the original maintenance plan if the server remains stable for another week or two. If we stay stable past that point, it should solidly confirm the maintenance plan as the source of the problem.